# JSON parsing in Opera throwing `Illegal number format (trailing decimal dot)`

Tags: javascript, json, opera, syntax-error

What kind of JSON could cause Opera 12 (it doesn't happen in other browsers) to throw the following error:

> `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: Illegal number format (trailing decimal dot)`

*Customers have told me they receive this error, but since they aren't very technical I haven't been able to guide them far enough to dig out the string. I've tried to reproduce the error myself but so far haven't succeeded. Hence, I don't know the JSON string causing this.*

Comment: When you say *"in Opera"*, are you saying it doesn't happen in other browsers?

Comment: Can you not `console.log()` the string you're passing to JSON.parse?

Comment: ...and what do you mean you don't have access to the string? How is it being parsed if it's inaccessible?

Comment: And in fact, the error message says exactly what the problem is. The number ends in a decimal point, which is an illegal format for JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a number literal with a trailing dot, it could cause this error, e.g.

```
{
  n: 1234.
}
```

Comment: ...this is another example of how JSON !== JavaScript